# post_logout_redirect_uri not working with localStorage in OIDC Auth2.0 client

Tags: javascript, angular, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect

```
           authority: 'xxx',
           client_id: this.'xxx',
           redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/login',
           response_type: 'code',
           scope: 'xxx',
           post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/logout',
           automaticSilentRenew: true,
           accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 60,
           silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/refresh',
           userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage })
       };

async signOut(): Promise<void> {
    
       this.manager.signoutRedirect();

   }
```

Using this OIDC client pacakages for SSO https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js
When I use localStorage as userStore , its not redirect back to post_logout_redirect_uri on sign out method but it's work fine if use default session store .
While using default session store .user close the tab and come again after some time and if session is expired then browser get hangs

Please let me know if anything is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to Authorization Server cookies being dropped, perhaps due to no User Gesture (top level navigation) when you open a new browser session?

Do your errors occur if you open a new Incognito window, use local / session storage, then login, then logout? Or do they only occur when you completely close a browser, then reopen it and try to logout?

**FOCUS ON ONE FEATURE AT A TIME**

If you can post more specific steps on reproducing each problem, starting with an Incognito window, I may be able to suggest further actions.

**SOME WORKING CODE TO COMPARE AGAINST**

In [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts) I store tokens in memory and multi tab state in local storage. Each new browser session tries to renew tokens silently and fails, then triggers a new login redirect.